# Can everyone with my passport data see my American arrival/departure record (form I-94)?

Tags: usa, i-94

[ICE](https://www.ice.gov/doclib/sevis/pdf/i94-fact-sheet.pdf) says, "Form I-94 is the DHS Arrival/Departure Record issued to aliens who are admitted to the U.S., who are adjusting status while in the U.S. or extending their stay, among other things."

In order to retrieve your I-94, you can just go to this website:

https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/recent-search

and a few personal data, and there you get your I-94.

I wonder whether every agency that knows my passport can look up my USA travel history. This includes foreign immigration offices, my own home country and also employers that collect too much data.

In fact, even if somebody knows my birthday and a few digits of the passport number, that is already enough to let software just run a brute force attack.

Are there any security measures in place that I am overlooking, and what can people do with my I94?

Comment: "what can people do with my I-94" is probably best asked as a different question, but in general the answer is that most people can't do anything useful with it.

Comment: The US is a very open country. If someone owns property, you can look up their full list of houses as well as how much they've paid for them on the county's legal registry.

Comment: @JonathanReez: That's interesting ... however, I am wondering whether foreign governments can crawl the county's legal registry.

Answer (score 21):

When you go to the I-94 website, you have to agree to a warning:

> By accessing this website, you understand and acknowledge that:
>
> You are declaring under penalty of perjury pursuant to 28 U.S. Code §
> 1746 that you: (1) are only seeking records about yourself, (2) are
> seeking records about someone for whom you are the legal guardian, or
> (3) you have the consent of the person whose records you are seeking.
> You are not authorized to access this website to retrieve records of
> another person unless you are the person's legal guardian or you have
> the person's consent.
>
> Unauthorized or improper use or access of this website, including the unauthorized or improper modification, destruction, or disclosure
> of any information or data contained herein, is expressly prohibited,
> and may result in civil and criminal penalties.
>
> The access and use of this website is subject to monitoring by DHS for administrative, law enforcement, or criminal investigative
> purposes, inquiries into alleged wrongdoing or misuse, and to ensure
> proper performance of applicable security features and procedures. DHS
> may monitor the access or use of this website without further notice.
> You may not process classified national security information on this
> website.

So at least on paper, it violates US law for someone else to look up your information unless they have your consent. But practically, there's not a deeply strong mechanism to enforce that, and people or entities outside of the US might not care that they're breaking US law. I wouldn't be surprised if there was some monitoring in place to detect bulk queries, brute force attacks, and abuse of the system, but it seems unlikely a rogue employer or someone else performing a single lookup would be caught and face consequences for that even if it is illegal.

If you click through to the privacy notice for the website, it does say that "CBP will retain the information submitted when attempting to access records through this website for 3 months for audit and system performance purposes," so there's at least a theoretical possibility they could identify some types of misuse from those logs. If you think your records have been misused, you could conceivably try [requesting a copy](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records) of those logs that pertain to you; I have no idea if they'll actually give them to you (or refuse because you're not a citizen/permanent resident, or perhaps misunderstand your request and just send you your I-94) or do so in a timely fashion or whether they'd be of any use.

So yes, anyone with the required information from your passport can see your travel history (or at least the potentially incomplete version displayed by the website).

Comment: "If you think your records have been misused, you could conceivably try requesting a copy" That would have to be within those mentioned 3 months, and whether that information will be actually useful... Long story short, it looks like the answer to "Are there any security measures in place" is No.